# filsh oauth2 in yii2(getting exception)

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, yii2, token

i am trying to implement filsh oauth2 in yii2. But i get

```
{
    "name": "Exception",
    "message": "Argument 1 passed to OAuth2\\GrantType\\ClientCredentials::__construct() must implement interface OAuth2\\Storage\\ClientCredentialsInterface, instance of common\\auth\\Identity given",
    "code": 0,
    "type": "TypeError",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\bshaffer\\oauth2-server-php\\src\\OAuth2\\GrantType\\ClientCredentials.php",
    "line": 25,
    "stack-trace": [
        "#0 [internal function]: OAuth2\\GrantType\\ClientCredentials->__construct(Object(common\\auth\\Identity), Array)",
        "#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\filsh\\yii2-oauth2-server\\Module.php(95): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)",
        "#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\filsh\\yii2-oauth2-server\\controllers\\RestController.php(25): filsh\\yii2\\oauth2server\\Module->getServer()",
        "#3 [internal function]: filsh\\yii2\\oauth2server\\controllers\\RestController->actionToken()",
        "#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
        "#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Controller.php(157): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
        "#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Module.php(528): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('token', Array)",
        "#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Application.php(103): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('oauth2/rest/tok...', Array)",
        "#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Application.php(386): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
        "#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\warehouse\\api\\web\\index.php(17): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
        "#10 {main}"
    ]
}
```

When i have try to POST my data to get access token:

```
{"grant_type" => "password","username" => "indigo","password" => "qwerty","client_id" => "testclient", "client_secret" => "testpass"}
```

[image]

Here is my api/config/main.php

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => 'json',
                'application/xml' => 'xml',
            ],
        ],
        ],
    'modules' => [
        'oauth2' => [
            'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
            'tokenParamName' => 'accessToken',
            'tokenAccessLifetime' => 3600 * 24,
            'storageMap' => [
                'user_credentials' => 'common\auth\Identity',
            ],
            'grantTypes' => [
                'user_credentials' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
                ],
                'refresh_token' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
                    'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'response' => [
            'formatters' => [
                'json' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                    'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
                    'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'user' => [
//            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\auth\Identity',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'enableSession' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '' => 'site/index',
                'POST oauth2/<action:\w+>' => 'oauth2/rest/<action>',


                'GET product' => 'product/index',
                'GET client' => 'client/index',
//                'GET product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
                'GET user' => 'user/index',
                'PUT,PATCH client' => 'client/update',
                'PUT,PATCH product' => 'product/update',
                'PUT,PATCH user' => 'user/update',

                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'product',
                        'client'
                        ],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'as authenticator' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\filters\auth\CompositeAuth',
        'except' => ['site/index', 'oauth2/rest/token'],
        'authMethods' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth'],
            ['class' => 'yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth', 'tokenParam' => 'accessToken'],
        ]
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'except' => ['site/index', 'oauth2/rest/token'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'as exceptionFilter' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\filters\ErrorToExceptionFilter',
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

and my common/auth/Identity.php

```
<?php

namespace common\auth;

use filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module;
use OAuth2\Storage\UserCredentialsInterface;
use common\models\Users;
use common\repositories\UserReadRepository;
use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Identity implements IdentityInterface, UserCredentialsInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(Users $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $user = self::getRepository()->findActiveById($id);
        return $user ? new self($user): null;
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        $data = self::getOauth()->getServer()->getResourceController()->getToken();
        return !empty($data['user_id']) ? static::findIdentity($data['user_id']) : null;
    }

//    public function getId()
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->user->id;
    }

//    public function getAuthKey()
    public function getAuthKey(): string
    {
        return $this->user->auth_key;
    }

//    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey): bool
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

//    public function checkUserCredentials($username, $password)
    public function checkUserCredentials($username, $password): bool
    {
        if (!$user = self::getRepository()->findActiveByUsername($username)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $user->validatePassword($password);
    }

//    public function getUserDetails($username)
    public function getUserDetails($username): array
    {
        $user = self::getRepository()->findActiveByUsername($username);
        return ['user_id' => $user->id];
    }

//    private static function getRepository()
    private static function getRepository(): UserReadRepository
    {
        return Yii::$container->get(UserReadRepository::class);
    }

//    private static function getOauth()
    private static function getOauth(): Module
    {
        return Yii::$app->getModule('oauth2');
    }
}
```

and also common/models/User.php

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use common\entities\AggregateRoot;
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;
use common\entities\events\UserSignUpConfirmed;
use common\entities\events\UserSignUpRequested;
use common\entities\EventTrait;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property integer $role
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property integer $phone
 * @property integer $count
 * @property string $date
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class Users extends ActiveRecord
{

    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%users}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
            [['username'], 'required'],
            [['role', 'phone', 'count', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
//    public static function findIdentity($id)
//    {
//        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
//    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
//    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
//    {
////        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
//        return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
//    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    public function isActive(): bool
    {
        return $this->status === self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
//    public function getAuthKey()
//    {
//        return $this->auth_key;
//    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
//    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
//    {
//        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
//    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }

//    public function fields()
//    {
//        return [
//            'id' => 'id',
//            'last_name' => 'last_name',
//            'username' => 'username',
//            'email' => 'email',
//        ];
//    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'role' => 'Role',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
            'count' => 'Count',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
            'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

}
```

UserRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace common\repositories;

//use common\dispatchers\EventDispatcher;
use common\models\Users;


class UserRepository
{
//    private $dispatcher;



//    public function __construct(EventDispatcher $dispatcher)
//    {
//        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
//    }

    public function findByUsernameOrEmail($value): ?Users
    {
        return Users::find()->andWhere(['or', ['username' => $value], ['email' => $value]])->one();
    }

    public function get($id): Users
    {
        return $this->getBy(['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function getByEmailConfirmToken($token): Users
    {
        return $this->getBy(['email_confirm_token' => $token]);
    }

    public function getByEmail($email): Users
    {
        return $this->getBy(['email' => $email]);
    }

    public function getByPasswordResetToken($token): Users
    {
        return $this->getBy(['password_reset_token' => $token]);
    }

    public function existsByPasswordResetToken(string $token): bool
    {
        return (bool) Users::findByPasswordResetToken($token);
    }

//    public function save(Users $user): void
//    {
//        if (!$user->save()) {
//            throw new \RuntimeException('Saving error.');
//        }
//        $this->dispatcher->dispatchAll($user-> releaseEvents());
//    }
//
//    public function remove(Users $user): void
//    {
//        if (!$user->delete()) {
//            throw new \RuntimeException('Removing error.');
//        }
//        $this->dispatcher->dispatchAll($user->releaseEvents());
//    }

    private function getBy(array $condition): Users
    {
        if (!$user = Users::find()->andWhere($condition)->limit(1)->one()) {
            throw new NotFoundException('User not found.');
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

i can't find solution to this problem or maybe there another way to solve(without dividing User entitie)

if i add oauth2 into "components" array then i have got

```
<response>
<name>Exception</name>
<message>Call to a member function getServer() on null</message>
<code>0</code>
<type>Error</type>
<file>
D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\filsh\yii2-oauth2-server\filters\auth\CompositeAuth.php
</file>
<line>14</line>
<stack-trace>
<item>
#0 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(75): filsh\yii2\oauth2server\filters\auth\CompositeAuth->beforeAction(Object(yii\rest\IndexAction))
</item>
<item>
#1 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
</item>
<item>
#2 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(557): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
</item>
<item>
#3 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(682): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
</item>
<item>
#4 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(145): yii\base\Module->beforeAction(Object(yii\rest\IndexAction))
</item>
<item>
#5 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('index', Array)
</item>
<item>
#6 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('client/index', Array)
</item>
<item>
#7 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
</item>
<item>
#8 D:\OSPanel\domains\warehouse.elisDN\api\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
</item>
<item>#9 {main}</item>
</stack-trace>
</response>
```

here config file

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => [
        'log',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => 'json',
                'application/xml' => 'xml',
            ],
        ],
        ],
    'modules' => [],
    ///api/web/oauth2/token
    'components' => [
        'oauth2' => [
            'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
            'tokenParamName' => 'accessToken',
            'tokenAccessLifetime' => 3600 * 24,
            'storageMap' => [
                'user_credentials' => 'common\auth\Identity',
            ],
            'grantTypes' => [
                'user_credentials' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
                ],
                'refresh_token' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
                    'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
//                'application/xml' => 'yii\web\XmlParser',
            ],
        ],
        'response' => [
            'formatters' => [
                'json' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                    'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
                    'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'user' => [
//            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\auth\Identity',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'enableSession' => false,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '' => 'site/index',
                'POST oauth2/<action:\w+>' => 'oauth2/rest/<action>',


                'GET product' => 'product/index',
                'GET client' => 'client/index',
//                'GET product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
                'GET user' => 'user/index',
                'PUT,PATCH client' => 'client/update',
                'PUT,PATCH product' => 'product/update',
                'PUT,PATCH user' => 'user/update',

                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'product',
                        'client'
                        ],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'as authenticator' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\filters\auth\CompositeAuth',
        'except' => ['site/index', 'oauth2/rest/token'],
        'authMethods' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth'],
            ['class' => 'yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth', 'tokenParam' => 'accessToken'],
        ]
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'except' => ['site/index', 'oauth2/rest/token'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'as exceptionFilter' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\filters\ErrorToExceptionFilter',
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: Did you upgraded your Yii2 version? Like `composer update`?

Comment: @Yupik, yes i did

Comment: So that's the problem, i remember that i did same and had exact problem, but i don't remember if that was yii2 or filsh module (or bshaffer).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your configuration.you have to include oauth2 configuration part into the components array, not into the modules array.

Comment: i did what you said(i have update the question), i have anoter "Exception", but thank you for your responce